# Indeterminate customized ProgressBar in Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

To create a personalized indeterminate ProgressBar with nice design and an animation like Android's native, I found the solution and looked very good:

[image]

Example:

1. Add this code in yours Main.axml file:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:background="#4286f4"
       android:minWidth="25px"
       android:minHeight="25px">
       <Button
           android:text="Show progress Bar"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:id="@+id/btnShow" />
       <ProgressBar
           android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
           android:id="@+id/progressBar"
           style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="4dp"
           android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar" />
   </LinearLayout>`

---

2. Add in Resources/draeable a new xml file named progress_bar.xml which contains:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <layer-list 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:id="@android:id/background">
       <shape>
           <corners android:radius="5dip" />
           <gradient
                   android:startColor="#ffffff"
                   android:centerColor="#ffffff"
                   android:endColor="#ffffff"/>
       </shape>
   </item>
   <item
           android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
     <clip>
       <shape>
          <gradient
                 android:startColor="#84b1f9"
                 android:endColor="#84b1f9"
                 android:angle="90" />
       </shape>
     </clip>
   </item>
   <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
   <clip>
     <shape>
       <gradient
            android:startColor="#ffffff"
            android:endColor="#ffffff" />
     </shape>
   </clip>
   </item>
   </layer-list>`

---

3. Add following code into MainActivity:

   ```
   public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
   {
       public Button buttonShow;
       ProgressBar progressBar;
       bool StopCondition=true;
       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

           // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
           SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
           progressBar = FindViewById<ProgressBar>(Resource.Id.progressBar);

           buttonShow = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnShow);

           buttonShow.Click += ButtonShow_Click;
       }

       private void ButtonShow_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
       {
           int progressBarStatus = 0;

           ///run thread for increase progress bar
           new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate {
               while (StopCondition)
               {
                   if (progressBarStatus == 100) progressBarStatus = 0;

                   progressBarStatus++;
                   progressBar.Progress =progressBarStatus;
                   progressBar.SecondaryProgress = 2*progressBarStatus;
                       Thread.Sleep(10);//// slep foe 100 ms

               }     
           })).Start();
       }
   }
   ```

You can access the source code in the link:

https://github.com/IonCojucovschi/progressbarXamarin

Comment: This sounds more like an answer than a question

Comment: This is an qestion wit my answer.  But if u hawe another solution u can show me

Comment: Use tasks, not threads. It's not relevant to an answer, but its good advice for you.

Comment: it is a good idea